# getting emptied while checking if an array value exists - laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I wanted to insert the `id` values of `$courseCat` if that id is not present in `$m`.In the below code, i feel the `$m` array is getting emptied every time and so, all id's are getting inserted to the `$m` ,as the result of `dump($m)` indicates.How can i fix this?

```
$m=[];
$courseCat = MyCourse::where('course_id', $key['courseId'])->get()->toArray();
foreach($courseCat as $k=>$c){
  // dump($courseCat);
    if(!in_array($c['id'],$m)){
           array_push($m,$c['id']);
      }
}
//dump($m);
```

`dump($courseCat);` shows the following result

```
    array:2 [
      0 => array:19 [
        "id" => 2
        "course_id" => 18
      ]
      1 => array:19 [
        "id" => 3
        "course_id" => 18
      ]                                   
    ]
   array:2 [
      0 => array:19 [
        "id" => 2
        "course_id" => 18
      ]
      1 => array:19 [
        "id" => 3
        "course_id" => 18
      ]                                   
    ]
    array:2 [
      0 => array:19 [
        "id" => 5
        "course_id" => 1
      ]                                
      1 => array:19 [
        "id" => 6
        "course_id" => 1
      ]
    ]
    array:2 [
      0 => array:19 [
        "id" => 5
        "course_id" => 1
      ]                                 
      1 => array:19 [
        "id" => 6
        "course_id" => 1
      ]
    ]
```

`dump($m)` shows the below result:

```
array:2 [
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
]
array:2 [
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
]
array:2 [
  0 => 6
  1 => 5
]
array:2 [
  0 => 6
  1 => 5
]
```

Below attached images are the result of the query `MyCourse::where('course_id', $key['courseId'])->get()`.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K47P1.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K47P1.png)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OerOH.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OerOH.png)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muVIF.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muVIF.png)

Expected result :

`dump($m)` should show the below result

```
[0=>2,
1=>3,
2=>5,
3=>6]
```

Comment: Can you dump the result of MyCourse::where('course_id', $key['courseId'])->get() this query

Comment: that `dump` of `$courseCat` doesn't make sense

Comment: @AmalSR i did. it also resulted the same what i've shown up in the question for `dump($courseCat);`

Comment: @lagbox what more should i show here?

Comment: the actual dump of the database result ... you wouldn't have things grouped like that or have the duplicates if this was right from that query

Comment: @user17699125 dumb the query result before converting to array. like
$courseCat = MyCourse::where('course_id', $key['courseId'])->get();
dump($courseCat);
like this.

Comment: I don't see why `MyCourse::where('course_id', $key['courseId'])->pluck('id')` wouldn't get you your list of 'id's

Comment: @AmalSR ,@lagbox, pls see the updated question. i've attched the screenshot of the query u asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you have an outer loop not shown in the question. You need to declare `$m` before the outer loop:

```
$m=[];

foreach($keys as $key){
    
    $courseCat = MyCourse::where('course_id', $key['courseId'])->get()->toArray();
    foreach($courseCat as $k=>$c){
      
        if(!in_array($c['id'],$m)){
               array_push($m,$c['id']);
          }
    }
    
}
dump($m);
```

Comment: U r right .I've an outer loop.But even after declaring `$m=[];` before that loop shows the result `array:2 [
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
]
array:2 [
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
]
array:4 [
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
  2 => 6
  3 => 5
]
array:4 [
  0 => 2
  1 => 3
  2 => 6
  3 => 5
]` for `dump($m);`

Comment: @user17699125 `dump($m);` need to put after outer loop

Comment: @user17699125 I mean `dump($m);`. Currently you put it inner the loop, so the `dump` function executed 4 times. Please see my answer that where the `dump($m);` placed on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the values of a column from your query you can use `pluck`:

```
MyCourse::where('course_id', $key['courseId'])->pluck('id')
```

Now you have a list of all the 'id's.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Database - Running Database Queries - Retrieving a List of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values) `pluck`

Comment: Yes. i can pluck id as such. My issue is not thta. My issue is that the `$m` array is getting emptied somehow & and so, all id 's are getting inserted to `$m` array by breaking my check.

Comment: you keep referring to this `$m` which is unneeded since you already have a list of the ids ... your code doesn't match the outputs or the things you are saying